# Best way to share among multiple Roles/Profiles

Tags: sharing, apex-managed-sharing, apex-sharing

Scenario: I have a requirement where I need to share records of some custom objects with users whose role could be anything say like region wise sharing. What could be the best way, till now in my org there were two to three persons in each region so we used to share it manually. Now team size has a huge increase and sometimes we require to downsize too so manual sharing is not a good option any more. Whether we go with apex sharing or no-code sharing but with ease of add/excluding users.

Please suggest a good solution.

Comment: You can go for creiteria based sharing, if its about sharing based on regions. Hope those region is also captured in User(to which region he belongs to)

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I need to add many users belonging to different roles whom I can't club in same profiles as well. Please advice

Comment: Can you please post the screen shot of that error.

Comment: No it's working fine, So I deleted my comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Use Public Groups for adding/remove users, And using Sharing Rules you can share with those Public Groups based on some criteria to grant Read Only OR Read/Write Permissions.

Public Groups - Setup | Administer | Manage User | Public Groups

Sharing Rules - Setup | Administer | Security Controls | Sharing Settings

Answer (score 1):

You can use [criteria based sharing rules](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_sharing_cbs_about.htm) to share records based on their region and set the [OWD](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_sharing_owd_about.htm&language=en_US&type=0) (organization wide defaults) to private and your criteria based sharing rules will open the record access for specific users meeting the criteria.